# How do I find the Kernal of a Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Say I have a Linear Mapping from $R^3 \to R^2$ defined by $L(x) = (x + y, y + z)$. I know that to find the **$\ker(L)$** you have to set $x + y = 0$ and $y + z = 0$. My question is, how did we get the vector (or answer) $(1,-1,1)$? I don't understand. Thank you.

Comment: $Ker(L)$ is basically the null space of $L$, which has a dimension 1 (Rank-nullity Theorem). Hence, we could have any vector of the form $v=(\lambda,-\lambda,\lambda)$ as the Kernel

Comment: A good first step is to write kernel and not kernal. :-)

Comment: Another good step is not to use $x$ to stand for $(x,y,z)$. Using the same letter for two different things in one equation is bound to cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If $x+y=0,~~y+z=0$ then you indeed have a line! The first equation is a plane and the other one is also. Solve these equations simultaniously as a system of linear eqations. If you  take $z=t$ then $y=-t$ and then $x=t$. So the set of all solutions are spaned with vector $V=(1,-1,1)$. This is a basis for that kernel.